# When can I use a plural noun with" the

Tags: articles

Are there any differences between

Berliners (in general)or the Berliners (more specific)  in which context or sentence could  I use "the Berliners" I can't find one

Comment: The Berliners I know are quite different from the common picture of Berliners.

Comment: Also if that was the name of a band or the title of a movie "The Berliners".

Comment: Leonard Gross, [The Last Jews in Berlin](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HsqVBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT170&dq=%22but+the+berliners%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22but%20the%20berliners%22&f=false): *But **the** Berliners rushing to their concerts and operas and plays and films reminded him of what the city had once been and what it had meant to him.* I don't say it would be *wrong* to discard the article there, but it certainly seems better in than out. It adds a sense of "immediacy" (even though [those particular] Berliners probably haven't been mentioned before, we sense their "presence").